# Llenar input's desde jquery mediante ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, input

Buenas tengo un pequeño dilema al seleccionar un dato de un `dropdownlist` haciendo uso de `Ajax` al procesar el código no me visualizan los datos en sus respectivos input como se ve en la imagen , intente 2 maneras para tratar de colocar la informacion en los input, no se si las 2 son validas o las 2 son incorrectas, mediante la consola se puede apreciar que la informacion esta obtenida de manera correcta a través del método pero no se sitúan correctamente.

```
    function SeleccionTratamiento() {
    var selectedVal = document.getElementById("MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_TRA_PAC").value;
    console.log(selectedVal)
    $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/Presupuesto/Get_Valor_Tratamiento",
            data: { 'TRA_CONCEPTO': selectedVal },
            success:
                function (resul) {
                    console.log(resul)
                    $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_PRE").empty();
                    $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_PRE").append(resul.trA_VALOR);
                    $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_POR").append(resul.trA_POR_DESC);
                    $("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_DES").val(resul.trA_DESC);
                }, error:
                function (e) {
                    alert("ERROR: " + e.message);
                }
        });
};
```

A continuación coloco mi código html.

```
  <div class="form-row">
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                @if (!Model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_ID.Equals(0))
                                                {
                                                    <label>Tipo Tratamiento:</label>
                                                    @Html.DropDownList("MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_TRA_PAC", new SelectList(Model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.Tratamiento_Lista, "Text", "Text"),
                                 new { @class = "form-control" })
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    <label>Tipo Tratamiento:</label>
                                                    @Html.DropDownList("MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_TRA_PAC", new SelectList(Model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.Tratamiento_Lista, "Text", "Text"),
         "ESCOGA UN TRATAMIENTO", new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "SeleccionTratamiento()" })
                                                }
                                                <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_TRA_PAC" class="text-danger"></span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                <label>Valor Tratamiento:</label>
                                                <input asp-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_VAL_PRE" type="number" readonly class="form-control" />
                                                <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_VAL_PRE" class="text-danger"></span>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-row">
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                <label>Porcentaje Dscto. Tratamiento:</label>
                                                <input asp-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_VAL_POR" type="number" class="form-control" />
                                                <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_VAL_POR" class="text-danger"></span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                <label>Descuento Tratamiento:</label>
                                                <input asp-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_VAL_DES" type="number" readonly class="form-control" />
                                                <span asp-validation-for="MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_VAL_DES" class="text-danger"></span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen que coloco es para indicar el porque en mi jquery no coloco el id en el ajax con . y si con _

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que estaría realizando incorrectamente?

Comment: Veo que en `JS` estás usando **MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_PRE** pero en la vista `html` usas **MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_VAL_PRE** y así con los demás `input`. La diferencia entre ambas es que en una usas punto y en otra un guion bajo para separar dos palabras. Es posible que por esa razón no se estén mostrando los valores.

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta, yo creería que no es por eso.

Comment: Intuyo que usas ASP.NET con jquery, desconozco un poco la sintaxis que utilizas con jquery y ese framework pero yo te recomendaría que lo hicieras mas de lado `JS` además, quizá me equivoque pero el append es para agregar mas elementos a tu DOM, para los inputs le vendría bien el `.val()`

Comment: Si efectivamente es `ASP.NET CORE` llamo a mi funcion en `Jquery` con `Ajax` pero al parecer algo me estoy comiendo que no se coloca el valor correctamente en los input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en el codigo:

```
$("#MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_DES")
```

no es un identificador en el DOM deberia en el codigo usar en los input algo asi en las clases

```
class="form-control MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_DES"
```

de esta mmanera desde el apuntador en jqueryu podria escribirlo asi

```
$(".MODEL_PRESUPUESTO_PRE_VAL_DES").val( resul.trA_DESC )
```

y evidentemente una clase apunta a todos los input en su caso podria incluso annadir un ID en el codigo HTML para ser un apuntador mas efectivo en el caso de los input